# m and mm file extension dilemma

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, objective-c

got a file named GeneralUtils.m and its header file.
Im using that as a shared methods in several IOS projects.

Question:
some of projects are compiling success.
but one of project throws error at compile time:than I'm changing m file extension to mm file.
and it compiles.but by the way;other projects does not compile and renaming again mm extension to "m" back again.

I want to understand the logic.
why some of my IOS project wants its extension as m and other one wants it as mm file extension

Error details :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "randIntBetween(int, int)", referenced from:
   -[Blah method1] in File1.o
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What's in that file? Which case is that the error from? And what is the error in the other case? (FYI, `mm` is for Objective-C++ files. So you must be mixing C++ and Objective-C.)

Comment: What do you mean the projects "want" a certain file extension?  If you're compiling a .mm file, you're compiling Objective-C++, which means the associated header is treated in a C++ context.  Perhaps you need an `extern "C" ` directive in order to prevent C++ from screwing with the linkage of your functions.

Comment: includes simple -methods only- . without any class declarations.
question is this :
4 amount of IOS project accepts GeneralUtils.m
1 amount of IOS project accept only GeneralUtils.mm and not m file?!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the header in an `#ifndef __cplusplus` macro?

Comment: dont know if __cplusplus is a reserved macro or what it is.But :
I put these
#ifndef GeneralUtilities_h #define GeneralUtilities_h
......my procecures #endif
I added 10 minutes ago.but didnt solved. maybe I gotto clear project first ?

Comment: `__cplusplus` isn't a "reserved  macro", the double underscore means it's a compiler feature.  You use it to make sure C++ doesn't poison your other headers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The extension .m means that it is Objective-C and the extension .mm means that it is Objective-C++. So those are different files and you should know what is in it.

Comment: ofsure. but didnt know mm file cannot call functions declared in m file

Comment: @N.Ramos - An mm file most definitely can call functions IMPLEMENTED in an m file.  But note that they should be DECLARED in an h file.

Comment: all m and mm files has its corresponding header files.not absent.